# Darkening a SCSS Mixin based on percentage

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I have a sass mix-in for my angular to do list, that lightens the color of the app as you go, 1 being dark blue, 50 being white.

How can I go about making the hover make each item's background 50-60% darker?

My mixin:

```
@mixin shades-of-blue ( $count, $startcolor ) {
    @for $i from 0 through $count {
        $background-color: lighten( $startcolor, $i + $i ); 

        .tasks:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            background-color: $background-color;
        }
    }    
}

@include shades-of-blue( 50, #2d89ef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using `mix` instead of `lighten`/`darken`, otherwise everything is white at around 26.

```
@mixin shades-of-blue ( $count, $startcolor ) {
    @for $i from 0 through $count {
        $background-color: mix(white, $startcolor, $i + $i);

        .tasks:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            background-color: $background-color;

            &:hover {
              background-color: mix(black, $background-color, 50);
            }
        }
    }    
}

@include shades-of-blue( 50, #2d89ef);
```

You can try it out here: http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: Excellent! Works just how I wanted it to, thanks for the help!